# Updating specific fields in MongoDB subdocuments (rmongodb)

Tags: r, mongodb, crud

I have some problems understanding the way how **specific** fields of a subdocument (as opposed to the **entire** subdocument) can be updated.

I seem to have understood how to query for certain field values in subdocuments, but I'm lost with respect to how a BSON document needs to be structured that only changes the fields queried.

**Still feel like I'm not fully understanding how how "plain MongoDB syntax" translates into R syntax and how the [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#update-operators) exactly work. Any hints in that respect would be greatly appreciated.**

### Preliminaries

```
pkg <- "rmongodb"
lib <- file.path(R.home(), "library")
if (!suppressWarnings(require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE))) {
    install.packages(pkg, lib=lib)
    require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE)
}

db      <- "__test"
ns.0    <- "user"
ns      <- paste(db, ns.0, sep=".")
con     <- mongo.create(db=db)
```

### Ensuring empty DB

```
mongo.remove(mongo=con, ns=ns)
```

## Inserting documents

**This section simply ensures some example data in the DB. It's just an auxiliary part which you can skip mentally!! Continue with section “Querying“ and see "Actual querying" to get an idea of the document structure which might be hard to grasp from the R code below.**

### BSON for document 1

```
blist <- NULL
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="host", 
    value="unittest.com")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "paths")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "1")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="path", 
    value="home")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/home")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "queries")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "1")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="query", 
    value="?somequery")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/home?somequery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish query:1
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "2")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="query", 
    value="?someotherquery")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/home?someotherquery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish query:2
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish queries
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish path:1
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "2")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="path", 
    value="somepage")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/somepage")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "queries")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "1")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="query", 
    value="?somequery")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/somepage?somequery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish query:1
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "2")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="query", 
    value="?someotherquery")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="url", 
    value="www.unittest.com/somepage?someotherquery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish query:2
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish queries
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish path:2
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish paths
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf) # finish buf

b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
blist <- c(blist, list(b))
```

### BSON for document 2

**EDIT 2012-01-23**

I removed this section to make the question a bit easier to grasp.

### Actual insert

```
sapply(blist, function(ii) {
    mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=ii)
})
```

## Querying

### BSON for query

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "paths")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$elemMatch")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "queries")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$elemMatch")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, name="query", value="?somequery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
> query
    paths : 3    
        $elemMatch : 3   
            queries : 3      
                $elemMatch : 3   
                    query : 2    ?somequery
```

### Actual query

```
> mongo.find.one(mongo=con, ns=ns, query=query)
    _id : 7      50feff31ba54a032514b6181
    host : 2     unittest.com
    paths : 4    
        1 : 3    
            path : 2     home
            url : 2      www.unittest.com/home
            queries : 4      
                1 : 3    
                    query : 2    ?somequery
                    url : 2      www.unittest.com/home?somequery

                2 : 3    
                    query : 2    ?someotherquery
                    url : 2      www.unittest.com/home?someotherquery



        2 : 3    
            path : 2     somepage
            url : 2      www.unittest.com/somepage
            queries : 4      
                1 : 3    
                    query : 2    ?somequery
                    url : 2      www.unittest.com/somepage?somequery

                2 : 3    
                    query : 2    ?someotherquery
                    url : 2      www.unittest.com/somepage?someotherquery
```

## Updating

### BSON for update

I would like to set the value of the `query` field in `query` subdocuments. I had a look at the [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update) and tried something like this (using the `$set` and `$` operators because there are arrays involved):

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$set")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "paths")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "queries")
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(
    buf, 
    name="name", 
    value="abcd"
)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
bnew <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)

> bnew
    $set : 3     
        paths : 3    
            $ : 3    
                queries : 3      
                    $ : 3    
                        name : 2     abcd
```

### Actual update

Apparently, this wasn't a good choice ;-)

```
res <- mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=query, 
    objNew=bnew, flags=mongo.update.multi)

> res
[1] FALSE
```

[2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#update-operators zU

Comment: Might be better to ask your `update` questions separately as the pool of people that can help you with the `R` syntax part is much smaller and the length of your question is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: Well, I see your point but the R syntax is key in this question. Plus it's hard to provide a reproducible example  without supplying actual DB values which in turn requires a "populate with R syntax" part.

Comment: Yikes. I tend to agree with JohnnyHK. It might be easiest to prototype exactly what you want to do with Mongo JS command line, then port to R.

Comment: I removed the code for the second document to make it a bit easier to know what's going on ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this for bnew:

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$set")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "paths.0.queries.1.query", "?newquery")
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
bnew = mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
```

this will replace the 2nd query in the 1st of queries.